# Tramp Ipython remote session: Problems with remote paths within code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, tramp

Here's my setup:

```
* Tramp on remote
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :dir /ssh:me@server.com|ssh:me@remote:/project/
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session :results output drawer
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/project/path/to/file/data.txt')
#+END_SRC
```

When I run the code, tramp complains that the file `'/project/path/to/file/data.txt'` does not exist.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

However, the file does exist on the remote, and if I switch to the org-babel session and type in the commands directly, then I don't get any errors.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: Are you sure Tramp complains about `/project/path/to/file/data.txt`? This path is in your python script; Tramp has no access to this script. Furthermore, the error message `FileNotFoundError` does not look like originated from Tramp.

Comment: Tramp does not complain. Python does. But that only happens when I eval the src_block with a `:dir` argument that requires Tramp. If I switch to the session with `C-c C-v C-z`, and paste the code directly on the remote interpreter session, the FileNotFoundError doesn't happen.

Comment: So I cannot help. Somebody shall debug `ob-ipython.el`.